# PL/SQL compilation error

Tags: plsql

What is wrong with the following statement:

```
DECLARE
  int_exists INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(ItemKey)
  INTO int_exists
  FROM BIR_TabsForDashboard
  WHERE ItemKey  = 'Position';
  IF( int_exists = 0 ) THEN --doesnt exist
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE BIR_TabsForDashboard ADD Position int  NULL';
  END IF;
END;
```

I get this report error:

```
ORA-06550: line 7, column 9:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ITEMKEY": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

What could be wrong? It seems to work when I use it on another table but for some reason it comes up with this error when I do it to this specific table?

Comment: Looks like your `BIR_TabsForDashboard` table has no column named 'ITEMKEY'.

Comment: ItemKey is not recognized as column.

Comment: Also I don't see anything to stop it attempting to add the `position` column again if you run the command twice, so your next problem will be `ORA-01430: column being added already exists in table`.

Comment: Please DESC BIR_TabsForDashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table `BIR_TabsForDashboard` does not have a column named `ItemKey`.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure** the **procedure** which you are using is should properly declared in the place which you are using it. For an example if it is under an **another user** and in an **another package** then it should be in that same order. The **username, package and procedure** name.